# Cannot display Fetched data to the UI in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

it doesn't show an error and the project works just fine. I can log the data to the console as well. but it doesn't display in the UI. this is a tutorial project on youtube

I'm getting data from the API and passing that to the tours and tour components. and Tour component displays the fetched data.

**App component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import Tours from "./Tours";
// ATTENTION!!!!!!!!!!
// I SWITCHED TO PERMANENT DOMAIN
const url = "https://course-api.com/react-tours-project";
function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [tours, setTours] = useState([]);

  const fetchTours = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const tours = await response.json();
      setLoading(false);
      setTours(tours);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(true);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTours();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <main>
        <Loading />
      </main>
    );
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <Tours tours={tours} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Tours component**

```
import React from "react";
import Tour from "./Tour";
const Tours = ({ tours }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="title">
        <h2>Our Tours</h2>
        <div className="underline"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {tours.map((tour, index) => {
          return <Tour key={tour.id} {...tours} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Tours;
```

**Tour Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Tour = ({ id, image, info, price, name }) => {
  return (
    <article className="single-tour">
      <img src={image} alt={name} />
      <footer>
        <div className="tour-info">
          <h4>{name}</h4>
          <h4 className="tour-price">AUD{price}</h4>
        </div>
        <p>{info}</p>
        <button className="delete-btn">Not Interested</button>
      </footer>
    </article>
  );
};

export default Tour;
```

Comment: How do we know the response has data in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the setting of state in the function and move it to use effect. Have the API call only return the list instead of having it retrieving the list and setting the state.

```
    const fetchTours = async () => {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const tours = await response.json();
          return tours;
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAndSetTourState = async () => {
         const data = await fetchTours();
         setTours(data);
         setLoading(false);
     }
     fetchAndSetTourState();
    }}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 useEffect(async () => {
   await fetchTours();
  }, []);
```

I think your UI has not updated after the data arrived. You need to wait for your data is fetched.

Comment: i did like that but still it doesn't show anything

Comment: Can you give me the tutorial link? I would like to help.

Comment: this is the link and the 2nd project is the one i have an issue. thank you so much